# Calculating highest point, lowest point, average altitude in specified area around click position in Cesium?

Tags: cesium, altitude

I have successfully computed the height of a location where user clicks in cesium but my next step is a bit complex. What I want to do is that when user clicks at some point on globe, at any zoom level, I want to calculate highest point, lowest point and, average altitude around click position (say a circular area of 1000 meters).